# Change the Order of Mouse Click Listener and Render Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On my Reactjs web application I have a listener that on right mouse click saves the mouse position and when the render method is called this saved mouse position is used.

However, in some cases the render method is called before the mouse position is saved and this leads to an error.

Is there some way to control the order these methods are called?

The code:

```
class MyComponent extendes React.COmponent{

constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
        mousePosition_ : null
    }

    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    ClickUpdate.add(this.update); 
}

update(mousePosition){
   this.state.mousePosition = mousePosition;
}

render(){

         // return <div> accourding to the mousePosition that save on update 

}

}
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant code?

Comment: @Chris add code idea

Comment: Oh deary me. Never set the component's state directly, you need to use `setState()`. I suggest doing some beginner React tutorials to get the basics of components, state, props and such.

Comment: I agree. You should never set the state directly (except when you need to in the constructor). Study some more React tutorials :) But to answer your question, try `this.setState({mousePosition: mousePosition});`. The issue is that render is never called

Comment: Sorry guys, i don't understand. i read the react tudorials and don't understand what you talking about

Comment: @Yanshof, read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate.